# Middleman localized template not loading only for 1 locale

Tags: ruby, localization, middleman

Im using middleman to render index.html.erb (int), index.us.html.erb (us), index.br.html.erb (br) to load localized content.

It works fine with all locales except for BR.

I have created `locales/br.yml`

```
---
br:
  hello: "Hello"
```

Also, my `config.rb` file has proper i18n activation.

```
# Country specific pages ('source/html')
activate :i18n,
         :mount_at_root => :int,
         :templates_dir => "html",
         :langs => [:int, :in, :us, :br]
```

When I visit `http://localhost:4567/br` it load **int** template for **br**

Also, please note if Im using the build source, it works perfectly fine. But I in development environment while running server with `bundle exec middleman` BR doesn't load correct template.

Please let me know if you need any more code from my side.

Comment: How do you mean by "it doesn't load the correct template" ? What does it load? Does it give an error in the console?

Comment: I have mentioned, for br it loads int template